# Select one random image file from a folder, rename it, and copy it, to another folder

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I'm attempting to create a "Image Changer" that can move an image from a folder on my local computer, rename it "wallpaper.jpg," and move it into a profile folder in Firefox, essentially changing it at random.

I need to write a batch file for Windows that will select a random image file from a folder, rename it, and then copy it to another folder. The old image file would then have to be overwritten each time to replace it in the new folder location. I'd still need a copy of that file to keep it in its original location.

FYI, it  doesn't need to be a batch file, but that is what I am used to.
Also it would be nice if could loop doing this in the background until I kill the command.

Thanks in advance for your help...

I tried running this

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd \particular\folder
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
copy "!file[%rand%]!" \different\folder
```

Which would copy the image to the other folder, but I was struggling to figure out how to rename it.
Really trying to wrap my head around using batch scripts.

Comment: Just use `copy "!file[%rand%]!" \different\folder\wallpaper.jpg`.

Comment: Yeah that worked, wow thanks!, I can't believe I missed something so obvious.

Comment: What would be a good way to go about looping this? After like x amount of time to run the command again?

Comment: Use a scheduled task to launch the batch file. Type *Task* in the Windows search box and choose *Task Scheduler*. Questions about how to use it should be asked at [su], as it's not a programming question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Just an fyi,for anyone looking at this later, I came across a very simple way to have the batch script continue changing images. Just use `:loop` at the beginning of the file then add `timeout /t` with however much time you want, and end with `goto loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming is just the action of moving a file to a file with a different name. That's why there's no rename command in GNU/Linux for example.
In your case `\different\folder\wallpaper.jpg` should do the trick i think.

Also be sure to test if Firefox supports you to change the wallpaper like that, or if it has to reload for it to change

Comment: Yeah, it only seems to work at relaunch, but it definitely worked, close enough I guess.